# What do Karisawa, Yumasaki, and Togusa do for a living?

Tags: durarara

In episode 6 of the first season of *Durarara!!*, we see that Kadota is gainfully employed doing some sort of construction-related manual labor.

[image: Kadota working on a fancy bathroom]

But his three buddies in the <s>Mystery Machine</s> Dollars van don't appear to do anything that would earn them a dime - they just drive around town doing god-knows-what. Karisawa and Yumasaki seem to spend stupid amounts of money buying light novels and merchandise and stuff; and I'm guessing it costs Togusa a pretty penny to fund his Hijiribe Ruri habit.

How do the three of them afford anything?

Comment: [Yumasaki](http://durarara.wikia.com/wiki/Walker_Yumasaki) works as a freelance ice sculptor. The rest, not too sure.